# jquery ajax call and j_security redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, websphere

Using Jquery (latest), IBM WebSphere 6.1 Server, Java JDK 1.5

Got a bit of a pickle for AJAX calls.  All of my AJAX calls are to URLs that are a part of my web.xml's security constraint that requires authentication.  Authentication is standard form based j_security so on every request to the secure/protected URL the container (WebSphere) will intercept that call and see if the authentication is good and if the authentication isn't good it will auto-redirect to the login page.  Pretty simple/standard and expected right I think.

Take a look at the following code.  Regardless of the client's authentication status (authenticated, not authenticated, timed out) the GET call (or post, doesn't matter) to that url ALWAYS returns a 200.  So there really isn't any easy way to figure out if we were redirected or not unless we evaluate the data that the server returns.

Perhaps I am missing something?  This seems really convoluted.  The only reliable way I've found to see if we were j_security redirected is to take the data coming back from the server and do a dom search for the j_password field.  But that seems really inefficient since that's something I have to do for *every* AJAX call in my application.  Some of our AJAX calls are to URLs that return JSON and some return HTML.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '<c:url value="/secure/supersecretthingy.html"/>',
        dataType: 'html',
        data:{
            requestDate: requestDate
        },
        beforeSend: function(request) {
        },
        complete: function(request) {
        },           
        success: function(data, textStatus, response) {
            var ll = $('<div id="#wee" class=""></div>').html(data).find("#j_password").length;
            //console.log(ll);
            $("#wee").remove();
            if ( ll != 0) {
                //console.log('we timed out says websphere!');
                window.location = '<c:url value="${GLOBAL_AJAX_TIMEOUT_PAGE}" />';
            } else {           
                //console.log("not timed out");
                dialogDiv.html(data);
            }   
          },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {   
              //console.log(errorThrown);
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the same problem see how I handled it: [How to handle authentication through AJAX with a java web app that uses form based login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444917/how-to-handle-authentication-through-ajax-with-a-java-web-app-that-uses-form-base)

Comment: Thanks svachon!  That's pretty much what I ended up doing but slightly different.  Some of our AJAX calls return JSON and others HTML so what we ended up doing is on our Controllers setting a response header that we could pick up on the client side.  If that header isn't set then we know we just got redirected by WebSphere's j_security and can handle it appropriately.

Comment: The only additional thing I had to do was if the controller returned JSON then I did not specify the dataType in the call.  This is because websphere will return HTML if j_security intercepts the request.